# Does .NET 4.0 come with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0?

Tags: .net, database, inno-setup

I want to distribute an app that uses "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" and .NET 4.0. I already found a way for my installer to download .NET 4.0 if required. I just want to know if this will automatically download "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" or do I also need to figure out a way to download it by itself. If yes, what exactly do I need to download and install on the user machine? (I'm using Inno Setup to create my installer). I don't use ClickOnce because I want to make an standalone .exe.

Comment: 4.0 should be available in Windows, but you should read the download page shown by @Jirapong for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% of this but OLEDB should come in separate setup. You can download installer from

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en

**Update**, If you would like to bundle with your installer then you have to do with WIX http://wix.sourceforge.net/ , It is XML base project you may have to use the Votive (VS.NET Plug-In) - http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html

/* WiX Script */

```
<Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Value="AccessDatabaseEngine.exe"/>
<CustomAction Id="InstallOLEDB" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallOLEDB" After="..." />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

For more info of WiX and best place to get start at http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/

Comment: Use this latest driver is always recommended, as it has an x64 one. But remember to update your connection string according to the download page :)

Comment: Remember to include WixUtilExtension

Answer (score 4):

No, .NET 4.0 does not come with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

You can download the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 installer from here: [How to obtain the latest service pack for the Microsoft Jet 4.0 Database Engine](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114)

Answer (score 2):

You would want this script for your Inno Setup:

**jet4sp8.iss:**

```
    [CustomMessages]
   jet4sp8_title=Jet 4

   en.jet4sp8_size=3.7 MB
   de.jet4sp8_size=3,7 MB


  [Code]
   const
    jet4sp8_url = 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/3/9/4393c9ac-e69e-458d-9f6d-2fe191c51469/Jet40SP8_9xNT.exe';

  procedure jet4sp8(MinVersion: string);
  begin
    //check for Jet4 Service Pack 8 installation
    if fileversion(ExpandConstant('{sys}{\}msjet40.dll')) < MinVersion then
        AddProduct('jet4sp8.exe',
            '/q:a /c:"install /qb /l"',
            CustomMessage('jet4sp8_title'),
            CustomMessage('jet4sp8_size'),
            jet4sp8_url);
 end;
```

I assume you know what to do with the code so I'll leave you to it!

Good Luck!

Nateeo.

Comment: Just tried that but I get an error after downloading the jet engine saying "An error occurred while installing the dependencies" and later they say "Jet 4" is the one failed. Any idea why? I'm using Windows Vista and I **already** have a version (at least 4.0) of JET installed.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what to do, but I think you should try your setup on another computer to confirm.