# How to read a wk3 file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, lotus

I'm need to read several hundred wk3 files (Lotus 3 Worksheet).  Is there a way to read them via C# without using Excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never done it, however, you may be able to access the contents of the file using an ADO.Net Provider. I've used this before to read Excel files without having Excel installed.

Now, before you add, "But I want to read Lotus WK3 files, not Excel files", note that in the Jet provider Engine Type strings [in the documentation for the **ADO** version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140022%28v=office.10%29.aspx) it has support for interacting with Lotus WK1, WK3 and WK4 files. There is a version available for .Net too in the [JET OLEDB provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx).

What this means is that you may be able to use ADO.Net to query the files as if they were a file source via the JET data provider. Note that you can get it for .Net (if you don't already have it) from the link in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289764/does-net-4-0-come-with-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0).

Another option would be to automate Lotus, outputting the data as CSV or another more easily accessed format.

Hope this helps, and good luck

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the  the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace in C#. I know you mention without using Excel, but this is as close as I was able to find.

MSDN mentions a `Workbook.Open()` method that uses C#:

[**Workbook.Open()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx)

```
Workbook Open(
    string Filename,
    Object UpdateLinks,
    Object ReadOnly,
    Object Format,
    Object Password,
    Object WriteResPassword,
    Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended,
    Object Origin,
    Object Delimiter,
    Object Editable,
    Object Notify,
    Object Converter,
    Object AddToMru,
    Object Local,
    Object CorruptLoad
)
```